# Lifty with sbt 0.10

Tags: scala, lift, sbt

I am try to learn scala with lift. So i started setting up my development environment. After sbt i try install Lifty (i used [this](http://blog.scaling-the-web.net/setting-up-my-environment-for-lift-developmen-0) article as manual). But i have a problem with my sbt:

```
> *lifty is org.lifty lifty 1.6.1
[error] Expected ':'
[error] *lifty is org.lifty lifty 1.6.1
[error]  ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lifty 1.6.x is aimed to be used with SBT 0.7.x. The error shown is due to the fact that Lifty 1.6.x is a SBT processor, while SBT from 0.9.x use plugins instead, so you would need [Lifty 1.7](https://github.com/Lifty/Lifty-engine).

To get started I would recommend you to use [SBT 0.7.7](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/downloads/detail?name=sbt-launch-0.7.7.jar) and Lifty 1.6.1 as there is a lot of information for these and they work beautifully. Please note that Lift has a very active and willing to help community, so you can also ask these questions in the [Lift mail list](http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb).